# systemctl --user Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, debian-stretch, dbus

When I run this commande in my Debian 9 VPS : `systemctl --user` I have this following error : `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`

This error appear on all users except the user root.

I already have the `dbus` `dbus-user-session` `systemd` `libsystemd-dev` `libsystemd`

This is my env :

```
USER=web
LOGNAME=web
HOME=/home/web
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
MAIL=/var/mail/web
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SSH_CLIENT=[CENSORED] 23459 22
SSH_CONNECTION=[CENSORED]  23459 [CENSORED]  22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
TERM=xterm
XDG_SESSION_ID=1824414
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
SHLVL=1
PWD=/home/web
OLDPWD=/home/web
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
```

I can't find a solution in the 3 first page of searching in Google.

Comment: I had that problem and solved it by installing openssh-server, then rebooting

Comment: I also get that error message when prepending with `sudo` while using the `--user` flag.

Comment: Du you have libpam-systemd installed?

Comment: Thank you @CraigHicks that was the clue I needed. I was seeing this error from Ansible when trying to install a user service in systemd. Turns out I had `become: yes` in the task. Removing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 43):

1. There must be a `/lib/systemd/systemd --user` process for the user you're running this for. Check with: `ps aux | grep systemd`. In my case the process didn't exist because I was trying to setup background services on another account, and that user wasn't logged in (the `systemd --user` process is normally launched at login). The solution was to run `sudo loginctl enable-linger $otherUser`, which keeps the `systemd --user` process running at all times.
2. `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` must be set. In my case it wasn't, so my command had to be `sudo -u $otherUser XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u $otherUser) systemctl --user`.

Comment: A year later, and this is still valid. Thanks! I was not affected by the first point but I was by the second one. (Running Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Main problem was linger for me. It was never clear that if said user LOGS OFF, all systemd --user services wills top automatically by default. To keep them running even with the user logs off, enable linger as the user. Check linger status `loginctl show-user yourusername | grep Linger`, enable it `loginctl enable-linger yourusername`

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue recently.
The fact is that service systemd-logind was not started.

Starting following service did the trick:

```
sudo service systemd-logind start
```

Comment: How is this better than other answers?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1100681)

Comment: @Toto : other solutions did not work for me. This is the only solution that worked.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you have forgotten to enable `pam` in the openssh configuration?

```
grep UsePAM /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
UsePAM yes
```

The part responsible for starting the user session is `pam_systemd`:

```
grep -R systemd /etc/pam.d/system-login 
-session   optional   pam_systemd.so debug
```

If you habe enabled debugging (`debug` pam option). You should see debug messages like:

```
$ journalctl -u sshd  -g pam_systemd
Jun 17 17:41:05 shaun sshd[3575212]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): pam-systemd initializing
Jun 17 17:41:05 shaun sshd[3575212]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): Asking logind to create session: uid=1000 pid=3575212 service=sshd type=tty class=user desktop= seat= vtnr=0 tty= display= remote=yes remote_user= remote_host=192.168.178.34
```

`logind` starts your user instance.

Comment: Pam is already on

Comment: I added the `pam` `debug` option to the original answer. So you can check what is going on in the system journal.

Comment: `/etc/pam.d/system-login` might also be found at `/etc/pam.d/systemd-user` (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS here).

Comment: (And I think there's a tiny mistake in your answer: in the second code block, `-session` should be just `session`, no?)

Comment: This answer is close to solution, but it lacks explanations as to why to look into PAM at all, as well as what to do to fix the issue. The solution is on this page: ```https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587674/systemd-not-detected-dockerd-daemon-needs-to-be-started-manually``` I suggest people start with @Dojo answer, and if it won't be enough, then try @griffinht and of course this answer by @Jürgen as part of debugging. But first of all, the @Craig comment on this answer is the prerequisite of the solution - yes, one needs to install `openssh-server` first, then reboot

Answer (score 3):

This is how I resolved it:

```
echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unix:path=/run/user/0/bus
```

Then in my script,

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/0/bus"
systemctl --user restart my-service
```

Comment: Did not work, get the same error.

Comment: The only solution that worked, the rest was already ok in systemd

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. All environment variables were set correctly. Then I listed the `/run/user/$UID` directory and found that the bus socket was owned by `root` and not by my user. Deleting the file and rebooting the system re-created the file with the correct permissions and this resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem running `systemctl --user stop bitcoind` from a cron job, via a Makefile in $HOME/.bitcoin. Using the answers above, I set and exported XDG_RUNTIME_DIR and DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, and it now works. Perhaps only one or the other was necessary, but without running `strace` from the cron job I didn't know which file or directory it was failing to find.

Answer (score 0):

Dobrinov's answer helped me to find the answer. I have set $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS to /run/user/$UID/bus then it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (`Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`) when running the following command on Ubuntu 20.04:

`systemctl --user mask tracker-store.service tracker-miner-fs.service tracker-miner-rss.service tracker-extract.service tracker-miner-apps.service tracker-writeback.service`

The problem was because of the alias:

`alias systemctl='sudo systemctl'`

It substituted the `systemctl` with `sudo systemctl` and sudo caused the error.